# GUI for Server Editions

Tags: 12.04, server, desktop-environments

I'm developing a Photo sharing app so that I can seamlessly upload to my photos to my Home Computer even when I'm too much far from my Home.

For this purpose I'm planning to setup my own Home server using PostgreSQL and Glassfish because I only know C and Java.

The question is that is there any GUI available for Ubuntu 12.04 Server Edition so that I can easily manage these stuffs? I never used a server environment before.

Answer (score 2):

Any desktop environment available for Ubuntu is available on the server edition of Ubuntu and can be installed as any other package with `apt-get`.

`ubuntu-desktop` will install the default Unity desktop, `kde-desktop` will install the Kubuntu KDE desktop, `lubuntu-desktop` will install the LXDE packages of the Lubuntu release and `xfce-desktop` the Xubuntu desktop environment.

Any of those will work for you, but there are other more "light" options. Please check the appropriate [`ubuntu wiki page`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI) for GUI setup in a server environment.

Answer (score 2):

For this type of server, where you actually *want* a GUI, I'd recommend just using the desktop edition and then installing the services you need. It's the same system, so anything you can do with Ubuntu Server can also be done with Ubuntu Desktop and vice versa.